# TypeScript enum index validation

Tags: typescript, validation, enums

Consider this code:

```js
export enum ResponseCodes {
    'Network error' = 5003
}

const code: ResponseCodes = 4000 // No error
```

1. The enum don't have such a key. Why there is no error?
2. How to force to use this construction below:

```js
const code: ResponseCodes = ResponseCodes['Network error']
```

Comment: Friendly advise,  don't use numerical enums for this case. Please take a look at the value which you are receiving after enum compilation.

Answer (score 0):

> The enum don't have such a key. Why there is no error?

`ResponseCodes` compiles to

```js
{
 5003: "Network error",
 Network error: 5003,
}
```

This is why `const code: ResponseCodes = 4000` does not throw an error. This is a drawback of numerical enums, every number is assignable to enum.

> How to force to use this construction below:

This code `const code: ResponseCodes = ResponseCodes['Network error']` is valid